# Dynatree js - Collapse specific node

Tags: javascript

I have tree loaded as below

```
1Home
    2.1 HS1
        2.1.1 Gallery1
    3.1 HS2
        3.1.1 Gallery3
```

My Goal is initially tree will be collpased and showing below output

```
1 Home
     +2.1 HS1
     +3.1 HS2
```

If I add Gallery 2.1.2 Gallery 2, After adding it It should expand 2.1 HS1 and show 2.1.2 Gallery 2 selected. HS2 should collapse. Below outout is expectd.

```
1Home
    2.1 HS1
        2.1.1 Gallery1
        2.1.2 Gallery2
    +3.1 HS2
```

Please help me how i can achieve above functionality

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following Property

`minExpandLevel: 1`

set it to `1` or whatever sets your requirement

e.g.

// In real life we would call a URL on the server like the following

```
checkbox: true,
selectMode: selectMode,
initAjax: { },
minExpandLevel: 0,
```